# Docker python multi-stage build is not smaller

Tags: python, docker

I am building a python app in Docker, and implemented a multi-stage build in hopes that it would slim down the image size. However the image appears to be the same size, and in fact 3mb bigger. Does anyone have any idea why this might be the case? This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Use lightweight Python image
# Image for base configuration step
FROM python:3.9.10-slim as base

ARG DOCKER_ENV

# PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 - Display trace if a sefault occurs.
# PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 - Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
# PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off - Disable pip cache for smaller Docker images.
# PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on - Ignore pip new version warning.
# PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 - Give pip longer than the 15 second timeout.
ENV DOCKER_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV} \
  PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
  PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
  PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100


# Image for build step
FROM base as build

# Set working directory in container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies for pg
# Don't use a virtual environment because it doesn't load dependencies properly
# Install poetry
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y gcc \
  libpq-dev python3-dev && pip install poetry

COPY ./appserv/pyproject.toml ./appserv/poetry.lock ./

# Install production dependencies
# --no-interaction: don't ask interactive questions
# --no-ansi: disable ansi output
# --no-dev: no dev dependencies
# --no-root: don't install project's package, we need this since our directory is empty at this point
RUN POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false poetry install \
  --no-interaction \
  --no-ansi \
  --no-dev \
  --no-root

# Copy app into container
COPY appserv /app


# Final image for running app
FROM build as final

# Run server
CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "gconfig.py", "app:app"]
```

Comment: You're never using a different image, so they are all building on each other - `FROM base as build` ... `FROM build as final`

Comment: Your first stage doesn't do anything and your 2nd stage starts from the first image. You likely won't see much improvement from multi-stage for languages like python even when done properly.

Comment: The general idea of using multi-stage builds is when you **`COPY` between stages**. For example, some C headers got installed, then poetry compiled some native code, and generated some output. That gets _copied_ to the next stage without the previously needed build-libraries, or the pip cache, but you still need to use `FROM` a clean base image that is compatible with what was previously built.

Comment: You're running `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y gcc \
  libpq-dev python3-dev && pip install poetry` and you don't expect size be more than the base image?